# How to get Oracle procedure comments from data dictionary

Tags: oracle, data-dictionary

How do I get Oracle procedure comments from the data dictionary (catalog) tables? Is there something similar to `ALL_TAB_COMMENTS`?

**Background:** The Oracle JDBC driver gives back a comment of "Standalone procedure or function" for a procedure, and "Standalone function" for a function, when using the [`getProcedures`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedures-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or [`getFunctions`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getFunctions-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) call respectively, in the `REMARKS` (explanatory comment on the procedure or function) field.

I want to see where this data is coming from, within the data dictionary.

Comment: What comments? The [`COMMENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4010.htm#SQLRF01109) statement doesn't apply to procedures. Before asking how to query it, make sure you know how to set it (and show how in the question).

Comment: the text column in `all_source` includes your procedure comments as well. Do a `where text like '%--%'` to see the lines containing single line(using --) comments.

Comment: See also: [What You Can Comment In Oracle Database](https://dataedo.com/blog/what-you-can-comment-in-oracle)

Comment: @Andreas - more details added to the question

Comment: That looks like hardcoded comments added by the Oracle JDBC driver, especially given that there are no comments in the data dictionary. Remember, JDBC applies to all database dialects, not just Oracle, and other databases may support comments on procedures and functions. I would have expected the comments to be null, but I guess the person writing the JDBC driver thought a hardcoded comment would be nice to have.